# I can call a method, but it's invisible for the Object#method method - how is it possible?

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming

I have a situation that is quite strange for me. I changed names of classes, because I work on client's code, but it looks like this:

```
(byebug) obj.method(:my_method)       
*** NameError Exception: undefined method `my_method' for class `MyModule::MyClass'

nil
(byebug) obj.my_method                
*** BERTRPC::UserError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3)

nil
```

And this method executes normally in the code. So, how is it possible that I can use method that seems not to exist?

Comment: Is it defined with `method_missing`?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I figured out this also a moment ago :)